Show that given any 4 points in the plane we can find two whose distance apart is not an odd integer
I tried using php but could not figure out the holes  .
Source1993 putnam B-5 : https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol9311.html ( the solution here is very bashy the other solution provided at the end skips quite a few steps ,which I could not understand)
